# SQL Server 2008 R2: Prepare dynamic where clause for given string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following string to convert into the `where` clause.

**Given string**:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Dateofjoining = '2015-01-01' AND Firstname = ''Sam'' AND Lastname = ''Mak'' AND PhoneNumber = 123'
```

**Note**: The given string used for condition check for the employee table where I am just getting an record of specific `firstName` and `LastName` of the employee. Now I want to add the `SOUNDEX()` function to the both ends of the given value in the string. So the expected `WHERE` clause should looks like as shown below.

**Expected result**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Employee2
WHERE Dateofjoining = '2015-01-01' 
  AND SOUNDEX(Firstname) = SOUNDEX('Sam')  
  AND SOUNDEX(LastName) = SOUNDEX('Mak') 
  AND PhoneNumber = 123;
```

Comment: Why are you assembling your query this way instead of making a stored procedure that accepts optional parameters?

Comment: @EricHauenstein, Yeah! I have created stored procedure for this. I have just simplified and posted to make better understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query would do your work -

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Dateofjoining = ''2015-01-01'' AND Firstname = ''Sam'' AND Lastname = ''Mak'' AND PhoneNumber = 123'
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Employee2
WHERE '
SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,1,PATINDEX('%AND%',@String)-1)+' AND '+
'SOUNDEX('+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String,PATINDEX('%AND%',@String)+3,dbo.Pos(@string,'''',1)+1),' = ',')= SOUNDEX(')+')'+' AND '+
'SOUNDEX('+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String,dbo.Pos(@string,'AND',2)+4,dbo.Pos(@String,'AND',3)-dbo.Pos(@String,'AND',2)-4),' = ',') = SOUNDEX(')+')'+' AND '+
SUBSTRING(@string,dbo.Pos(@String,'AND',3)+4,LEN(@String))
SELECT @Sql + @string
```

The function code to find the occurrence of `'` -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Pos(@string VARCHAR(MAX),@delim VARCHAR(10),@occur INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos int, @counter int, @ret int
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string)
set @counter = 1
if @occur = 1 set @ret = @pos
else
begin
while (@counter < @occur)
begin
select @ret = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string, @pos + 1)
set @counter = @counter + 1
set @pos = @ret
end
end
RETURN @ret
END
```

**Edit:** Made changes as per the requirement.

Comment: plus1 almost done. But please check I have edited string around 22 min ago.

Comment: I overlooked the changes and posted based on earlier query, modified it now. Let me know if this fits.

Comment: The `Dateofjoining` and `PhoneNumber` is attached to given string they are not separate.

Comment: Made the changes, hoping that your initial `SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Employee2
WHERE` can be configured in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
create table #temp(Num int,FName Varchar(50),SName varchar(50))
insert into #temp values(1,'Sam','Mark')
insert into #temp values(1,'Jan','Feb')

DECLARE @Con1 VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @Val1 VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @Con2 VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @Val2 VARCHAR(MAX) 
set @Con1  = 'FName' 
set @Val1  = 'Sam'
set @Con2  = 'SName' 
set @Val2  = 'Mark'

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @str='SELECT * FROM #temp
WHERE SOUNDEX('+@Con1+') = SOUNDEX('''+@Val1+''')  
 AND  SOUNDEX('+@Con2+') = SOUNDEX('''+@Val2+''')'

 Execute(@str)

drop table #temp
```